# How to optimize a non-convex function with nonlinear equality constraints

Tags: nonlinear-optimization, constraints

\begin{equation}
\min \|X-UV\|
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\textbf{s.t.} \|Uz_i\|_{2}=1
\end{equation}
with $V_{n\times m}=(z_1,z_2,...,z_m), z_i=(v_{i1},v_{i2},...,v_{in})^{\top}$

Comment: What are the variables in your optimization problem?  What are $X$ and $U$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The constraint $\|Uz_i\|_2=1$ is the same as $\|Uz_i\|_2^2=1$. If for the norm in the function $\|X-UV\|$ there exists a $p\geq 1$ such that $\|X-UV\|^p$ is differentiable, then the problem is equivalent to minimize $\|X-UV\|^p$ subject to $\|Uz_i\|_2^2=1$. To do this use Karush-Kuhn-Tucker Theorem.

Comment: thanks for your answer. But in fact, I also have two more constraints which are U>0 and V>0. So KKT theorem cannot be applied here because of too many constraints. Three constraints and only two equalities deriving  from the derivatives of lagrange function. It's unsolvable. (T_T)